# Программно развернуть форму

Tags: c#, winforms

Каким образом при нажатии кнопки формы "Развернуть" сделать все компоненты данной формы соответствующими размеру окна?

Comment: @Андрей WinForms

Comment: Боюсь, что общего ответа на ваш вопрос нет. Разные компоненты растягиваются/отрисовываются/выравниваются по-разному. Уточните какие именно компоненты не растягиваются так, как нужно.

Comment: @АлексСкай, используйте свойство `Anchor`

Answer (score 2):

Следование этим правилам позволяет создавать гибкие и сопровождаемые пользовательские интерфейсы:

1. Старайтесь никогда не класть элементы управления непосредственно на форму.  Используйте "умные" контейнеры типа [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Для самих элементов управления используйте свойства[`Dock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`Margin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.margin(v=vs.110).aspx).
3. Используйте для элементов управления [`AutoSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx), когда нужно чтобы элемент управления подстраивался под размеры своего содержимого.